# Add markers from UITableViewController to UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController`, inside of this one in my storyboard I have a `UITableViewController` and a `GMSMapView`.

Well, I have a service to populate my `UITableViewController`, with some information and georeferences. The `UITableViewController` behavior is working perfectly, but when I try to access to my `UIViewController` the markers aren't added.

```
class RequestViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!
    var solicitudes = [SolicitudesModel]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 83.4824182, longitude: -88.1776567, zoom: 15)
        self.mapView.camera = camera

        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(13.4824182, -88.1776567)
        marker.title = "My location"

        marker.map = self.mapView
    }

}
```

The marker as this point was added.

```
class RequestTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var reqs = [RequestModel]()

    @IBOutlet var RequestTable: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        var requestVC = RequestViewController()

        Alamofire.request(UrlGlobals.retriveInformation()).responseJSON { response in
            let json = JSON(response.result.value)
            var i: Int = 0

            self.reqs.removeAll()
            for _ in json.array ?? []  {
                //Some code to populate the table

                let marker = GMSMarker()
                marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(CLLocationDegrees(json["lat"].float!), CLLocationDegrees(json["lng"].float!))
                marker.title = "Some title"

                marker.map = requestVC.mapView

            }
            self.RequestTable.reloadData()

        }
    }
}
```

The json retrieves all the information correctly. How I can access to my primary ViewController and add those google markers?

Comment: I don't get the point: What is the workflow between the ViewControllers? Do you start with the RequestTableViewController and then want to display the RequestViewController, or is it the other way round and you start with the RVC, open the RTVC and want to propagate the result back to the (primary) RVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now your RequestViewController is an instance that exists only in viewDidLoad. Make it a class property and you will be able to access it anywhere.